# Can webpack download and bundle javascript modules referenced in HTML?

Tags: webpack

I have the following sample HTML file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@github/auto-complete-element@3.5.1/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import {
                html,
                render
            } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html@2.8.0/lit-html.js'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to run webpack and have all the referenced javascript module files downloaded from the referenced URLs and then the URLs rewritten to refer to a copy of the module stored at a relative path.

I have tried to use a webpack configuration file like the following:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

After running `npx webpack` the output html file has the white space removed but the URLs referencing the external javascript remain the same.

Is this something that webpack can be configured to do?